# Update Software proposes an upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 even if it is a 32bits netbook

Tags: upgrade

If UBUNTU discarded the 32bits old machines, how come Software Updater tool suggesta and  pushes to upgrade my 32bits netbook from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04?   I did it once and the netbook got stuck in the login procedure, it ask for password and it seems to log in but it returns to the password request again (no msg of incorrect password).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You can turn off requests for updates in System Settings > Software and Updates > Notify me of a new Ubuntu version and select Never

This will then leave you free to make your own decisions on what version to upgrade to according to availability and your own choice.

Comment: Ok thank you, it will be my choice, but why does it suggest to upgrade? I can always say NO but I wander if I should upgrade instead.  The UBUNTU designers suggest me to upgrade or to stay with 16.04?

Comment: @danilio Sometimes it is better to remain in control rather than just leave matters to the developers as I think is the case here and from your earlier experience. I guess in the majority of cases, providing the option to upgrade is in their mind but there are now fewer exceptions and that number is diminishing. Perhaps you would be kind enough to accept the answer or at least upvote it?

Comment: i hope i upvoted correctly. Tks for you help

Comment: @danilio Thanks for accepting the answer. You can upvote an answer by clicking on the up arrow above the green tick.